# How to remove specific bullet points containing text in Google Slide using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I would like to remove specific bullet points from a Slide in Google Slide that contain the text {{remove}} inside them.

I found this code but it applies for Google Docs, not Google Slide.

Can this be done in Google Slide ?

Here's the code:

```
function removeListItem() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var noOfChildren = body.getNumChildren();
  var childrenToRemove = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < noOfChildren; i++) {
    var child = body.getChild(i);
    var childType = child.getType();
    if (childType == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      if (child.asListItem().findText("{{remove}}") !== null ) {
        childrenToRemove.push(child); 
      }
    }
  }
  
  childrenToRemove.forEach(function(child) {
    try {
      body.removeChild(child);
    }
    catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e)
      if (e == "Exception: Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section.") {
        body.appendPageBreak()
        body.removeChild(child);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: About `I would like to remove specific bullet points from a Slide in Google Slide that contain the text {{remove}} inside them.`, I cannot imagine your Google Slide. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your sample Slide including the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike Hello and thank you for your assistance. Sure, Slide 1 is the input and Slide 2 is the output: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/19pPYHB4KCYwQO4GYjEYDtxovJijboubQPK6hKrCgFiE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your provided sample Slides, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
      const listParagraph = shape.getText().getListParagraphs();
      if (listParagraph.length > 0) {
        listParagraph.forEach(p => {
          const range = p.getRange();
          if (range.asString().includes("{{remove}}")) {
            range.clear();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

- In this script, all slides are scanned. If you want to use the specific slides, please modify `slides` of `slides.forEach`.

#### Testing:

When this script is run on your sample Slides, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [getListParagraphs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getlistparagraphs)

Comment: you are a legend. It works perfectly and as intended. Thank you!

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying and testing it. I could correctly understanding your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.